# Image uploading doesn't work in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Here is my controller:

```php
<?php
  if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('no direct access allowed');

 class Import_data extends CI_Controller
 {
   function __construct() 
   { 
    parent::__construct(); 
    //$this->load->helper('url');
    //$this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('upload');
   } 
  function index()
  { 
  }
 function image_upload()
  {
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['file_name'] = 'photo_' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 16);
        $image = 'aaa';
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($image))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            print_r($error);die;
            $this->load->view('home_view', $error);

        }
        else
        {   
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            print_r($data);die;
            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to print error message which prints:

> Array ( [error] => You did not select a file to upload. )

I don't know what is wrong in my code. I am selecting file properly, here is my view code:

```
<form name="" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('import_data/image_upload');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="excel_file" /> <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <?php //echo $error;?>
    <br/>
    <?php //echo $upload_data;?>
</form>
```

Comment: try to use $this->load->library('upload', $config) in image_upload() after set config array.

Comment: i tried this but no luck again same message Array ( [error] =>

You did not select a file to upload.
)

Comment: where are you using `$_FILES['excel_file']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is right code.  $this->upload->do_upload('excel_file')

File input field name must be passed here.

Answer (score 0):

Where you pass file name "excel_file" >> to $this->upload->do_upload('file_name');

Comment: i was passing $image that i was doing wrong i needed to pass file name in do_upload('filename') .

Comment: $this->upload->do_upload('excel_file');